# Adding string to javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

I need something like this:

Think that I have already have a project module.(which includes js files,package.json,html files vs)

What I need is to add some strings to specific files.(Not by manually.I need to do it by running extra command from terminal or something else).

For example I need to add extra modules to package.json devdependencies.And add some strings to js files.And I don't want do it by manually.I need that changes to be automatically.(By running extra command or something else.)

How can I create module,project or plugin for that?What can I use for that types of changes?
Any suggestion?

Comment: gulp taks https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using creating simple command here 'add_string' using shell or python etc language and add to it your package.json script.

'npm run add_string' will install new packages and add a string to your javascript files.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "add_string": "sh add_string.sh"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**add_string.sh**

```
for pkg in "express" "moment"
do
   npm i $pkg --save
done

for filename in *.js; do
  echo "/**Author name : abc@example.com **/" >> "$filename"
done
```

Also, you can save extra modules dependencies using npm i --save

Comment: @javauser35, are you looking for something like this?